# How to add class Source(src) class folder in Jsp Project Using Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, jsp

we have created Jsp Project, in that we had written Java class and use external jar file. Project is running fine in my local tomcat server, while when we deploy it in the main server we don't have access of web apps folder they gave me server access FTP and am sending that my project to that it deploying  but only client side code run it show  Error when server side code comes

http://www.incometaxindiapr.gov.in/incometaxindiacr/cbdt-cir-not/Home.jsp  please check this 
 class file not compile 
i think i am Unable to add class file please help how to add class file an all.

Comment: You need to import the classes from the package ! `import mypackage.LuceneFields.*;`

Comment: yes i did if u want to see my source code  i can show u

Comment: Show only the relevant part , I think this is a highly confidential site !

Comment: can u please give me ur email id so that i can show ur sorce code please and u can check where am doing wrong

Comment: You shouldn't write java code in JSP . Now that you have written , just check if all the imports are correct , then check the servlet file which gets generated from the JSP .

Comment: yes that URl is relvent part i am deplying in that my Project please check

Comment: where servlet file generates we have Only web.xml file

Answer (score 0):

If it runs locally and not able to run while deploying to Server, then first thing what I think you should check is, when you transfer your war to server using FTP at that place only, WAR which is transferred is in correct format,

I mean whether .class files are all transferred and in classes folder only. if all this is correct check versions mismatch. rest can be checked by logs only.

Comment: Am not deploying war file i m sending whole Project to server coz when send war file it not working on That please help am facing this issue from last 2 week please help

Comment: i mean to say if you send (war/or anything), things which are needed to make it run and in way Web Project is structured, is it the same after sending through FTP at server end. just compare your project structure in local and at server...is it all same?

Comment: yes coz when i deploy war file using tomcat manager in local server tehn Project autmatic extract its web apps folder and its workign Fine in local server But when sam Project folder i sent to main server using file zila then only client side code run server side code having those Error which coming in currnt URL please help

Comment: that is why I am telling the folder which you got in your local after extracting, please compare that folder with the folder you transferred using FTP.. is it all same?

Comment: yes it is same please tell email id so that i can show u My project please deploy it please help me. i got deadeline actually

Comment: please tell how to do ?

Comment: tell me ur email id... i will drop test mail on it.